# N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I have recently upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. Now if I install or remove any software, it shows-

```
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

How can I get rid of this message?